# Is there an upper bound for $\pi (n)-\pi (n/2)$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Is there a nice upper bound for $\pi (n)-\pi (n/2)$ where $\pi$ is the prime counting function?

[image]

Comment: $\frac{n}{2}$? :)

Comment: Have a look at the inequalities given at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function

Comment: Let me guess : You try to prove Bertrand's postulate .

Comment: Bertrand's postulate was about lower bound.

Comment: A constant bound? Wouldn't that contradict the Prime Number theorem???

Comment: No, a bound which is a function of $n$

Comment: Well, there are infinitely many of those. I think you need to "pinpoint" the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\frac{n}{ln(n)}<\pi(n)<1.25506\frac{n}{ln(n)}$ for $n\geq 17$

See [Rosser, Schoenfeld 1961](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ijm/1255631807) corollary 1.

Provides:

$\pi(n)-\pi(\frac{n}{2})<\left(1.25506\frac{n}{ln(n)}-\frac{\frac{n}{2}}{ln(n/2)} \right)$

[image: Bound Comparison from 1 to 200]

Comment: I would have rewritten this as: $$\frac{n}{\log n}\left(1.25506-\frac{0.5}{1-\log_n 2}\right)$$ Makes it much easier to see the implicit $\frac{n}{\log n}$ in the formula.

Comment: This is much nicer.

Comment: Since $\pi(2x)-\pi(x)\sim \frac{x}{\log x}$, for any $\epsilon$ there is an $N_{\epsilon}$ such that for $n>N_{\epsilon}$, $$\pi(n)-\pi(n/2)<\frac{n/2}{\log(n/2)}(1+\epsilon).$$