# Who proved that $\pi(n) < 1.25506\frac{n}{ln(n)}$?

Tags: prime-numbers, upper-lower-bounds

Who proved that $\pi(n) < 1.25506\frac{n}{ln(n)}$?

I am trying to write a paper that relies on this inequality, but I cannot find the citation and I want to be certain the inequality was proven.

Edit:
I looked at the Rosser and Schoenfeld paper "Approximate formulas for some functions of prime numbers" and it mentions the inequality as corollary 1 but no proof is provided

I also looked at the Wikipedia page on the Prime-counting function and it gives a crude explanation. I would be a fool to quote Wikipedia in my paper.

Comment: Are $n$ and $x$ related?

Comment: Oops. Sorry about that. I fixed it.

Comment: first with some constant was Chebyshev; not sure it was your 1.255

Comment: FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cpi(x)%5Clt%201.25506%5Cfrac%7Bx%7D%7B%5Cln(x)%7D%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Aprimes&p=1), there's [$\frac{x}{\log(x)}<\pi(x)<1.25506\frac{x}{\log(x)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4102734), but which was automatically deleted last year as an abandoned question. However, it includes a link to Wikipedia's [Inequalities](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function#Inequalities) section, with that article giving a reference to Schoenfeld, Lowell (1962), at ...

Comment: (cont.) [Approximate formulas for some functions of prime numbers](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/illinois-journal-of-mathematics/volume-6/issue-1/Approximate-formulas-for-some-functions-of-prime-numbers/10.1215/ijm/1255631807.full). There are also other related question, such as [Is there an upper bound for $\pi (n)-\pi (n/2)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1598683) that uses, & references, this result, and [An Inequality Involving The Riemann Zeta Function](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/984280) which just simply uses it.

Comment: I looked at the Rosser and Schoenfeld paper and it mentions the inequality as corollary 1 but there is no proof provided.

Comment: When something is called a corollary, but no proof is given, that usually means that the authors are convinced that with a little bit of work you can deduce the result from some previous result which they did prove. Have you tried to do that?

Comment: Earth to Kenneth; come in, please.